# Show Snackbar Reactively Using GetX in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

This is the scenario

1. Making an API call
2. Response is empty
3. Need to show 'No results found' msg to the user through Snackbar from GetX controller
4. But I don't want to pass the instance of the view class to the controller to show the Snackbar.
5. Is there any Getx widget that listens to the msg.obs value in the controller and executes Get.Snackbar() code in the view

Comment: Create a separate class helper to handle the changes of snackbar. Then pass the message to that class if there so no data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my knowledge, I think unlike BLoC there's nothing like `BlocListener` or `BlocConsumer` in GetX. But you can use `RxWorker` to achieve this like:

```
ever(someObservable, (){

    doSomething(); // show dialog, snackbar, navigate to other pages

 }
```

Just remember you need to put this before the `return` of your `build` method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code for show snackbar in flutter

```
 Get.snackbar(
    "Hello",
    "Thank You!",
    snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
    colorText: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor:  AppColors.toastGreenColor ,
    icon: Image.asset(
      "assets/images/success_toast.png",
      height: 25,
      width: 25,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was asking

Comment: Explain in brief